# Minimum order and multiples in data validation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the minimum order qty in H1
I have the multiplier in H2 (multiplier means in multiples of)

If minimum order qty is 10 and multiplier is 2, in cell H5 to H100, the user can type anything equal to or more than 10 and in multiples of 2, which means he can type 10,12,14,16,18,....

I don't want a drop down.

Is it possible to achieve by data validation?

How else can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use a custom formula for data validation:

Use this formula on cell range H5:H100: `=AND(H5>=$H$1,MOD(H5-$H$1,$H$2)=0)`

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

The marked entries from cell H5 are invalid.

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: It works well. But, it allows an entry of "4 2"  (space in between). It coverts to a date and allows the entry, even though it is wrong entry

Comment: It shows as invalid for me, maybe you can use ````Reject Input```` option to disallow them altogether.